# Node.js write http request response

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using this code to make an HTTP request to my own server. I'm getting the appropriate response in `chunk`.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var options = {
                    host: '<my ip>',
                    port: 8080,
                    method: 'GET',
                    path: '/content?data='+somedata
                };
    var call = http.request(options, function(res){
        res.setEncoding('utf8');                
        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            console.log("got response"+chunk);
        });
    }).on("error", function(e){
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
    call.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

My question is how I can print this chunk to my browser?

Comment: sorry I'm quite new to node.js. I was unaware about the scope of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change one of your two `res` variables to have a different name. At the moment the response to your request is masking the response you are trying to make.

Then:

```
response.write(chunk);
```

See also: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback

Comment: `var call = http.request(options, function(response){
 response.setEncoding('utf8');    
 response.on('data', function(chunk){
  //do something with chunk
  //console.log("got response"+chunk);
  //finaldata = chunk;
  response.write(chunk);
 });
 
}).on("error", function(e){
   console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});`

Gives me response.write is not a function.

Comment: @AakshayeMGaikar — That's because you're trying to write to the wrong response (i.e. the one you got back from your request, not the one your server is trying to make). You have to use the outer response object.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still quite new to Node.js. It worked for me now.

Answer (score 0):

```
res.write(chunk);
```

also don't forget to end first call, so the browser will know the request has ended.

```
res.end("success");
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still quite new to Node.js